# Trouble with printing from a text file with multiple lines of data

Tags: java, file-io

I have a text file with multiple lines of numbers like this:

```
0.0336    0.0243    0.0261 
0.0075    0.1788    0.0669
```

I need to make a Java program to reformat them to one number per line:

```
0.0336    
0.0243    
0.0261    
0.0075    
0.1788    
0.0669
```

Here is my code and it does not work:

```
while (scanner.hasNext())
{
   String[] arr = scanner.nextLine().split("\\s+");
   for(int i =0; i< arr.length; i++){
      System.out.println(arr[i]);
   }
}
```

This code results in an extra line whenever there is a new line, for example:

```
0.0336    
0.0243    
0.0261
       //extra line here, which should be ignored 
0.0075    
0.1788    
0.0669
```

Is there a way to ignore the line?

Comment: Your code should work with the input you shown. Or is there a white space before the first entry of a line? Or other special/unprintable character in the input file?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same you did it's working fine on my text file. I did this

```
BufferedReader source = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/path/of/file/stack.txt"));
scanner = new Scanner(source);
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    String[] arr = scanner.nextLine().split("\\s+");
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(arr[i]);
    }
}
```